# Sheet Name Changes Every time

Tags: excel, vba

My Sheet Name Changes everytime, how could I make this dynamic that it will still run the VBA code even if the sheet name has been change from the outside.

```
Sub Send_Range_Or_Whole_Worksheet_with_MailEnvelope()
'Working in Excel 2002-2016
    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    
    If Len(Range("B20").Value) = 0 Or Len(Range("B21").Value) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    

    

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Fill in the Worksheet/range you want to mail
    'Note: if you use one cell it will send the whole worksheet
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B22")

    'Remember the activesheet
    Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    With Sendrng

        ' Select the worksheet with the range you want to send
        .Parent.Select

        'Remember the ActiveCell on that worksheet
        Set rng = ActiveCell

        'Select the range you want to mail
        .Select

        ' Create the mail and send it
        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
            ' some header text to the email body.
            .Introduction = "Please see Quality Review Sev 1 details below."

            With .Item
                .To = "danielle.a.ext@razer.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = Range("E2").Value
                .Send
            End With

        End With
        
        MsgBox "Email Sent"

        'select the original ActiveCell
        rng.Select
    End With

    'Activate the sheet that was active before you run the macro
    AWorksheet.Select

StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: If someone changes the worksheet name all the time, then use the sheet **code name**. Also, qualify all the ranges e.g. `Sheet1.Range("B20")` , `Sheet1.Range("B21")`, `Sheet1.Range("A1:B22")`, `Sheet1.Range("E2")` for a worksheet (with the code name `Sheet1`) in the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`).

Comment: If the sheet name changes, how should your code identify which sheet should be used?